# Apps on my phone not loading files

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am relatively new to app development and Xcode, and I was recently building an app for a friend that included several images and sound files. When I ran the program on Xcode's iPhone simulator, the app worked fine and loaded the images correctly. However, when I downloaded the app on my phone, the files were no longer there and the app crashed whenever I tried to access them! Is there some way to include images and sound files when I download an app to my phone? This seems like a pretty major issue, so I assume I'm missing something here.

Thank you!

EDIT: SOLVED. The issue was that the files were not part of the app's bundle.

Comment: You have not provided any useful details. Update your question with relevant code, error messages, and an indication of how/where you attempt to access these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I ran the program on Xcode's iPhone simulator, the app worked fine and loaded the images correctly. However, when I downloaded the app on my phone, the files were no longer there and the app crashed whenever I tried to access them

Make sure that the files (images etc.) are part of your app's bundle, and then access them only by way of `Bundle.main` (Objective-C `[NSBundle mainBundle]`. The best way to ensure that they are part of the app bundle is to look in the app target's Build Phases and look at the Copy Files build phase. If the files are not there, they won't be included in the app bundle and you won't be able to access them.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me and saved me a lot of headache!

Comment: I should mention that another approach is to use the asset catalog.